# how can I set the table and figures on the right as the text

Tags: tables, floats

Somebody can help me out with my program?

```
    \documentclass[a4 paper, 11pt,twoside]{article}
        \usepackage{fullpage}                           % Makes the page margins smaller to a predefined one.
        \usepackage[lmargin=0.6in,rmargin=0.6in,tmargin=0.6in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{forloop}
        \usepackage{etoolbox}
        \usepackage{calc}
        \usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs} % To produce the empty space on the left
        \usepackage{xtab} % To produce the empty space on the left
        \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
        \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
        \usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
        \allsectionsfont{\color{Brown}}
        \makeatletter
        \def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
        {\csname the#1\endcsname\;}%  default
        {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% individual control
        }
        \def\section@cntformat{\thesection.\;} % Dot after the section number
        \def\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\;} % Dot after the subsection number
        \makeatother
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{
            colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=black,
            citecolor = black}
        
        \urlstyle{same}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        
        \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,epstopdf,url}
         \usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
         %\usepackage{makeidx,lscape}
         %\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}
        %\usepackage{upgreek}
        \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
        \usepackage{stmaryrd}
        \usepackage{tabularx, multirow,threeparttable}
        
            \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}
            \newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
            
        \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
        \usepackage{csquotes}
        \makeatletter
        \RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
        \makeatother
        
        \addbibresource{References.bib}
        
        \begin{document}
        
        the main body text...
    \begin{figure}[!tb]
        \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{D:/Ph.D/Dissertations.Books.reference/maps/1opt-local}
        \caption{Methods of searching local optimum}\label{h}
        \end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of the performance metrics between AMOPSO-SRD, SMOPSO, NSGA-II, and SPEA-II for the Viennet(4) test problem}
\label{tab:viennet4}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
 \begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
     Metrics & AMOPSO-SRD & SMOPSO & NSGA-II & SPEA-II\\
  \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    GD  &    0.012228 &  0.008051 &  0.012867 &  0.013069 \\
    S   &    0.084413 &  0.124016 &  0.158684   & 0.065328 \\
    C(A,B) &         -- &    0.010000 &  0.120000 &  0.100000 \\
    C(B,A)&          -- &    0.208000 &  0.264000 &  0.434000 \\
  \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
        
        \printbibliography
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
        
        \end{document}
```

the figure and the tables appear in this way, I want them align with the text
[image]

Comment: There is no `\end{figure}` in you code

Comment: why is this tagged biblatex or apa?? please use `example-image` as the test image as that is generally available and post code which shows your problem, as it is we can not run your example and you do not say what output you get or what output you want

Comment: do not use `epsfig` package in any document written after 1994